# Mapping entity field in JPA/Hibernate with session.get()

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Why do not I can create new Address with using:

```
AddressEntity ad = new AddressEntity(); 
ad.setCityId(session.get(CityEntity.class, 343))
```

but it works in this way:

```
Query<CityEntity> query = session.createQuery("from CityEntity where id = 343", CityEntity.class);
 query.setFirstResult(0);
 query.setMaxResults(1);
 List<CityEntity> listCity = query.getResultList();
 ad.setCityId(listCity.get(0));
```

Address entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class AddressEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "address_id")
    private Short addressId;
    ...
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private CityEntity cityId;

}
```

City entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class CityEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "city_id")
    private Short cityId;
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

I fell like I don't know something useful, but I can't understand what is it

I was trying get and set id by session.get() and by query

Comment: Have you tried `session.get(CityEntity.class, Short.valueOf(343))`?

Comment: I have tried now, but it looks like "session.get(CityEntity.class, Short.valueOf((short)343))"and it works perfectly, tysm!

Comment: upd. also it works just as "session.get(CityEntity.class,(short)343))", thx a lot again, your comment gave much impact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the primary key (`@Id` property) is defined as `Short`, but Java converts the 343 in `session.get(CityEntity.class, 343)` to an `Integer` by default; so JPA searches for a `CityEntity` with *Integer* id, which does not exist.

Giving it a `Short` will do the trick; either:

```java
session.get(CityEntity.class, Short.valueOf(343))
```

Or:

```java
session.get(CityEntity.class, (short) 343)
```

In the latter case Java will still "box" the short literal to a `Short` object.